# Prob. 7, Sec. 18, in Munkres' TOPOLOGY, 2nd ed: Functions continuous from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}_l$ and from $\mathbb{R}_l$ to $\mathbb{R}_l$

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Here is Prob. 7, Sec. 18, in the book *Topology* by James R. Munkres, 2nd edition:

> (a) Suppose that $f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is "continuous from the right," that is, 
>   $$ \lim_{x \to a+} f(x) = f(a), $$
>   for each $a \in \mathbb{R}$. Show that $f$ is continuous when considered as a function from $\mathbb{R}_l$ to $\mathbb{R}$.
>
> (b) Can you conjecture what functions $f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ are continuous when considered as maps from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}_l$? As maps from $\mathbb{R}_l$ to $\mathbb{R}_l$? . . .

I think I am clear about the proof of Part (a).

Here is my attempt at Part (b):

Maps from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}_l$:

> Suppose that $f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}_l$ is continuous. Then,  for any real numbers $a$ and $b$ such that $a < b$, as the "closed-open" interval $[a, b)$ is a basic open set for $\mathbb{R}_l$, so the inverse image set $f^{-1} \bigl( \ [ a, b) \ \bigr) $ is open in $\mathbb{R}$; thus for any real number $p$ such that $p \in f^{-1} \bigl( \ [ a, b) \ \bigr) $, that is, such that $a \leq f(p) < b$, we have an open interval $(c, d )$ containing $p$ such that $(c, d) \subset f^{-1} \bigl( \ [ a, b) \ \bigr)$, that is, such that $a \leq f(x) < b$ for any real number $x$ such that $c < x < d$.
>
> In particular, for any given $p \in \mathbb{R}$ and for any given real number $\varepsilon > 0$, as the set $\left[ \ f(p), \ f(p) + \varepsilon \ \right)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}_l$, so the inverse image $f^{-1} \bigl( \ \left[ \ f(p), \ f(p) + \varepsilon \ \right)\bigr)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$ and contains the point $p$. So we can find a real number $\delta > 0$ such that $f(p) \leq f(x) < f(p) + \varepsilon$ for every real number $x$ which satisfies $p-\delta < x < p+\delta$.

Is what I have done so far correct? If so, then what next? If not, then where have I erred?

Maps from $\mathbb{R}_l$ to $\mathbb{R}_l$:

> Suppose that $f \colon \mathbb{R}_l \to \mathbb{R}_l$ is continuous. Then,  for any real numbers $a$ and $b$ such that $a < b$, as the "closed-open" interval $[a, b)$ is a basic open set for the range space $\mathbb{R}_l$, so the inverse image set $f^{-1} \bigl( \ [ a, b) \ \bigr) $ is open in the domain space $\mathbb{R}_l$; thus, for any real number $p$ such that $p \in f^{-1} \bigl( \ [ a, b) \ \bigr) $, that is, such that $a \leq f(p) < b$, we have a "closed-open" interval $[ c, d )$ containing $p$ such that $[c, d) \subset f^{-1} \bigl( \ [ a, b) \ \bigr)$, that is, such that $a \leq f(x) < b$ for any real number $x$ such that $c \leq x < d$.
>
> In particular, for any given $p \in \mathbb{R}$ and for any given real number $\varepsilon > 0$, as the set $\left[ \ f(p), \ f(p) + \varepsilon \ \right)$ is open in the range space $\mathbb{R}_l$, so the inverse image $f^{-1} \bigl( \ \left[ \ f(p), \ f(p) + \varepsilon \ \right)\bigr)$ is open in the domain space $\mathbb{R}_l$ and contains the point $p$. So we can find a real number $\delta > 0$ such that $f(p) \leq f(x) < f(p) + \varepsilon$ for every real number $x$ which satisfies $p \leq x < p+\delta$.

Is my reasoning in this case correct? If so, then what next? Or else, what is wrong with what I have done?

Comment: What is $\mathbb{R}_l$?

Comment: @freakish $\mathbb{R}_l$ denotes the set of real numbers in the lower limit topology, which is the topology having as a basis all the "closed-open" intervals $$ [a, b) \colon= \{ \ x \in \mathbb{R} \ \colon \ a \leq x < b \ \},$$ where $a$ and $b$ are any real numbers such that $a < b$.

Answer (score 0):

Try to show that all continuous functions from $\mathbb{R}$ (usual topology) to $\mathbb{R}_l$ (Sorgenfrey/lower limit topology) are constant functions.